# How to do vanilla js equivalent appendChild in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, appendchild

I have already written [this](https://codepen.io/sivadass/pen/XZEVmM) pen in vanilla js. Now I want to use it inside my react component.

```
renderPDF(url, canvasContainer, options) {
  options = options || {
    scale: 1
  };

  function renderPage(page) {
    var viewport = page.getViewport(options.scale);
    var wrapper = document.createElement("div");
    wrapper.className = "canvas-wrapper";
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var renderContext = {
      canvasContext: ctx,
      viewport: viewport
    };
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;
    wrapper.appendChild(canvas);
    canvasContainer.appendChild(wrapper);

    page.render(renderContext);
  }

  function renderPages(pdfDoc) {
    for (var num = 1; num <= pdfDoc.numPages; num++)
      pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(renderPage);
  }
  PDFJS.disableWorker = true;
  PDFJS.getDocument(url).then(renderPages);
}
```

When i use the above render function inside componentDidMount lifecycle of react, am getting the error of `Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null`

Please guide me to code the above function in the react way?

Here is my current [code-sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ywzrr7qm1z)

Comment: What is `canvasContainer`?

Comment: That is canvas wrapper ref, i have defined it in component did mount.

Comment: Are you sure that that is being passed through as expected? `wrapper` isn't `null`, as I can see it clearly defined there, which means the only other contender for a null error is `canvasContainer`.

Comment: Actually canvasContainer element is present inside a Modal component which is provided by a ant-design, but am using that ref inside componentDidMount of its parent component,  that is the App component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Modal component not render at first time because of `this.state = {visible: false};` so `.modal-container` does not exist at first render. It will be rendered only after your click on 'Open' button.

To avoid this you could move pdf creation logic into separate component and render this component inside `<Modal>`. Here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/wz5xry98w)

Comment: Thank you so much,  this what i want to achieve :)